# Android RecyclerView adds space at the bottom of each Item

Tags: android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I use [MaterialList](https://github.com/dexafree/MaterialList) library to display card views and in some projects each card view has extra space after it (I cannot post a picture since I need 10 reputation...). **Any idea why?**

**Update**
The above occures when I am running the library's sample code from within my application. Everything is ok when running the sample code as is (I made no changes to the sample code in order to run it from within my application).

Comment: how about viewing the source code of MaterialList Library source code for the relevant code which creates a layout of CardView?

Comment: Please see update.